# Unable to import the localized component from one environment to other

Tags: content-porter-2009

We have a publication "030 CP Content" on DEV CMS which is inheriting "020 Global Content", and same blueprint has been imported to QA CMS.
In 030 CP Content on DEV, we have localized one component "XYZ" which is coming from 020 Global Content. On QA, we have created a group grpCPUSER, a user usrCPUSER and mapped usrCPUSER with grpCPUSER. Group grpCPUSER is a member of Information Designer, Template Designer, Chief Editor, Publication Manager and Interaction Manager for 030 CP Content. For publication 030 CP Content, under security tab, we have added grpCPUSER and assigned it the following rights:

1. Publication Management
2. Folder Management
3. Structure Group Management
4. Schema Management
5. Component Management
6. Component Template Management
7. Page Management
8. Page Template Management
9. Permission Management
10. Category Management
11. Template Building Block Management
12. Virtual Folder Management
13. User Generated Content

An export of "XYZ" component is being taken from DEV (excluding all dependencies) and we tried to import it on QA (excluding all dependencies) by using credentials of usrCPUSER via content Porter. But, import is failing with an error "Current user has no enough rights to Edit item "/webdav/030 CP Content/Building Blocks/Content/Common/ForgotPassword_Email.xml". Provide import user with enough rights or skip import of current item and all items that depend on it.". Although user usrCPUSER has rights to localize the component at 030 CP Conetnt but still we are getting this error. Are we are missing on any pre-requisites to get this done or there’s some other issue? Please assist.

Comment: The rights may be alright, but have you checked the permissions on the folder as well?

Comment: It seems like it's the problem on the folder itself. It might be thay user is not able to localize component

Answer (score 2):

This seems a known issue and appropriate hotfixes for Content Porter are available [HERE](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/ContentPorter_2009/index.aspx)

In specific, apply following hotfixes and try:

1. CP_2009.0.70433
2. CP_2009.0.67032

Applying these hotfixes should resolve the issue.

**Please Note:**
In our case (which is similar to yours), after applying the above said two hotfixes, fixes the issue for components, but still if we have a localized Structure Group, we were not able to export/import.

You may want to verify it for your case.

Comment: Same user (usrCPUSER) can localize the component via CMS Explorer and by using the sysadmin account we are able to import that component also we are using CP 2009 SP2 and CMS is CMS 2011 SP1. Please also provide us more details about these hotfixes

Comment: You seems perfectly ok from hotfix perspective. Can you please share the screen shot of permissions (Read,Write, Localize, Delete) for the User on the specific folder in which the Component is available.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to follow the authorization setup and confirm why this should (or shouldn't work).

By default `Chief Editor` will have `Component Management` rights. The other roles aren't necessary, but all you need is the `Component Management` right (along with the correct permissions).*

Adding additional rights for `GroupContentPorterUser` shouldn't be needed (since it belongs to `Chief Editor`, which has `Component Management` rights and rights are transitive).

If the following are set correctly and the same user can do the same action in Content Manager Explorer in QA, double check the item's status (is it locked?) and consider following up with support.

**Permissions**

As Pankaj hints at, your `Common` folder should give `GroupContentPorterUser` (it could be the user itself, but it's easier to manage permissions at a higher group level) localize permissions. Setting `localize` automatically sets `read` and `write.`

The group should also have `read` to the schema that `ForgotPassword_Email` depends on.

**Scope**

Confirm you do not have scope restriction (missing `030` somewhere) in either user's membership in the ContentPorter group or in the ContentPorter group's membership in `Chief Editor`.

It's up to you, but my preference is to leave the "available for" setting to `All Publications` and only manage the differences membership of one group to another.

**Item Status**

Also confirm the item isn't in workflow or otherwise locked (checked out) by another user.

**Rights and Exceptions**

Maybe not the real issue, especially since both your ContentPorter group and `Chief Editor` both have `Component Management` rights, but just in case, double check the 030 publication settings as well as any exceptions (`Show Exceptions` check box at the bottom of authorization tab). Rights are set separately per publication and aren't "BluePrinted."

**Also, I've seen at least one implementation that intentionally prevented localization that caused issues later on since the settings somewhat hidden (actually it was my fault).**

If it's really at item status or permissions issue then the error message is misleading. Tridion authorization really breaks down to just permissions (on folders), scope (in group membership), and rights (in publications).

Comment: 020 Global Content is Global Publication which is managed by a central team and is inherited by many other publications of different projects and on those child publications different teams work according to their project.So we can’t give write/localize access on global publications like 020 Global content to those teams as it is managed by a central team only. Although in 030 CP Content user have right to localize and modify the components inherited from Global Publication from Content Manager Explorer.Same user can do the same action in Content Manager Explorer in QA and item is not locked

Comment: Makes sense, I wouldn't recommend giving localize permissions in the folder at 020. Definitely follow up with Support, your setup *should* work since Content Porter authorization matches the CM(E). I might be nitpicking to point out `localize` *rights* don't apply to publications. Rights are the *what* (set in publications) and permissions are the *where* (organization items). Access and authorization would be better generic words when talking about Tridion settings.